# What permission does Logitech Control Center need?

Tags: mojave, peripheral

I have recently downgraded to a Logitech MX Anywhere first-generation mouse (the one that requires a receiver and without multi-device switching). Got it paired successfully with my Mac and have the basic functions but the Logitech Control Center software does not recognize the mouse so I cannot customize any button.

Every time I open Logitech Control Center in System Preferences, the following dialog box pops up:

> System policy is blocking Logitech system extension from loading, which may result in some Logitech devices not working properly.

I checked the Security & Privacy panel and found only 1 item for Logitech Control Center: under Automation

[image: Security & Privacy panel]

[Logitech's support article](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023202814-Important-information-for-Logitech-Control-Center-and-macOS-Catalina-and-Mojave) (bottom of page) shows that the item under "Logitech Control Center Daemon" to be "Finder" instead of "System Events".

How can I get Finder under there or give Logitech the permission it needs?

Mac OS X 10.14.6 Mojave. Logitech Control Center 3.9.10